# How Can I Get The Error Number in my try catch?

Tags: c#

How Can I Get The Error Number in my try catch ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Exceptions usually do not have error numbers. Are you trying to get the associated HRESULT for some interop purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Error Number in some specific Exceptions. Like sql exceptions and other.
But other wise you can get error message, error data and other stuffs
Try to explain a little bit more.